# Detecting a hover and changing an image with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way of doing the following ? I have a carousel which goes through five slides, and I have some buttons above it. If a button is hovered, I change to the corresponding slide in the carousel . It works, but I wondered, is this the correct approach in jQuery?

```
    $('#cat_0').mouseover(function() {
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#slide_0').addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#cat_1').mouseover(function() {
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#slide_1').addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#cat_2').mouseover(function() {
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#slide_2').addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#cat_3').mouseover(function() {
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#slide_3').addClass('selected');
    });

    $('#cat_4').mouseover(function() {
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $('#slide_4').addClass('selected');
    });
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$('[id^="cat_"]').mouseover(function() {
    $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
    $('#slide_' + (this.id.substring(4))).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as shown below:-

Jquery:-

```
$('.btn').mouseover(function() {
    alert("sfg");
        $('#carousel > li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
```

HTML :-

```
<input type="text" id="state" value="test" />
<input type="button" value="button1" class="btn"/>
<input type="button" value="button2" class="btn"/>
<input type="button" value="button3" class="btn" />
<input type="button" value="button4"  class="btn"/>
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/42/